# Webpack5 how to minimize copying assets such as images

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, copy-webpack-plugin

I have following **webpack.config.js** file, from this configuration I managed to compress all images which are consumed from css files.

But I also want to compress all images which I'm copying into dist folder.

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
 module: {
    rules: [

        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },

        {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
            use: [
                'file-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true,
                        },
                        // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
                        optipng: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        pngquant: {
                            quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                            speed: 4
                        },
                        gifsicle: {
                            interlaced: false,
                        },
                        // the webp option will enable WEBP
                        webp: {
                            quality: 75
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
        }
    ],
},
plugins: [
    // copying static assets to dist directory, i want these images to be compressed as well
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [{
                from: "source/images",
                to: "images"
            } 
        ],
    })
]};
```

How can I achieve this in webpack 5?

I saw this nice article (https://web.dev/codelab-imagemin-webpack/) explaining how this can be achieved but as it seems imagemin-webpack-plugin is not updated recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using the `copy-webpack-plugin` with `image-minimizer-webpack-plugin` minimizer. My config looks something like this.

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: 'path/to/images/*',
                    to({ context, absoluteFilename }) {
                        return "dest/[name][ext]";
                    }
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
                loader: true,
                minimizer: {
                    implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
                    options: {
                        plugins: [
                            "imagemin-gifsicle",
                            "imagemin-mozjpeg",
                            "imagemin-pngquant",
                            "imagemin-svgo",
                        ],
                    },
                },
                generator: [
                    {
                        type: "asset",
                        implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminGenerate,
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                "imagemin-gifsicle",
                                "imagemin-mozjpeg",
                                "imagemin-pngquant",
                                "imagemin-svgo",
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
    },
}
```

This portion of the docs led me to this solution.
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/#generate-webp-images-from-copied-assets